# Finding the index of an item in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, indexing, integer

If I have this list of lists:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13]]
```

How might I be able to find the index of the sublist itself according to the value given?

For example:

If my value is 2, The index returned would be 0

If my value is 9, the index returned would be 1

if my value is 11, the index would be 2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
l = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13]]

# e.g.: find the index of the list containing 12
# This returns the first match (i.e. using index 0), if you want all matches
# simply remove the `[0]`
print [i for i, lst in enumerate(l) if 12 in lst][0]
```

This outputs:

```
[2]
```

Edit:

[@hlt's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398259/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list-of-lists/25398310#comment39613911_25398310) comment suggests using the following for more efficient behavior:

```
next(i for i,v in enumerate(l) if 12 in v)
```

Comment: This finds all occurrences. You need to use `[0]` or (more efficient) turn the thing into an iterator and just extract the first element with `next` (i.e. `next(i for i,v in enumerate(l) if 12 in v)`)

Comment: @hlt: Thank you for your comment. You're quite right! Updated.

Comment: @hlt, why i replace 12 with variable produce error? NameError: name 'item' is not defined

Answer (score 4):

Either use a list-comp as demonstrated by @jrd1 if you want all indices, or if you want just the *first* occurrence, then:

```
next((idx for idx, val in enumerate(your_list) if 2 in val), None)
```

We use `None` here as a default value instead of raising a `StopIteration` where the value is not found in any sublist. Remove the default value if you wish the exception raised instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have many queries and/or a dynamic list of lists, then you are better off making a map. Specifically a value:set map. Where you map the value to a set of indices (sub-lists) that contain that value. Though this works best if the list doesn't change.

Example for `[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9,10], [11,12,13], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]`:

```
# Code for populating the map
map = collections.defaultdict(set)
index = 0
for i,v in enumerate(l):
    for _ in v:
        map[index].add(i)
        index += 1

# Result:
map = {
    1: {0,3},
    2: {0,3},
    3: {0,3},
    4: {0,3},
    5: {1,3},
    6: {1,3},
    7: {1,3},
    8: {1,3},
    9: {1,3},
    10:{1,3},
    11:{2,3},
    12:{2,3},
    13:{2,3}
}
```

You can also treat the sub-lists as intervals (covering a range of indices) and allowing for O(log N) look up and O(log N) add/remove sublist/element by building an [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). It takes O(L log L) to build the interval tree where L is the number of sublists.

Comment: That looks less than elegant. It makes sense, don't get me wrong, but it looks so bad, compared to `next((idx for idx, val in enumerate(your_list) if 2 in val), None)`.

Comment: It only looks ugly because I only gave the result of what I had in mind. Added the for-loop (I'd be interested to see it done as a one-liner). Also added a note about using an interval tree.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an (albeit somewhat inefficient, yet concise) recursive solution:

```
def get_index(lst, num, index=0):
    if num in lst[index]:
        return index
    else:
        return get_index(lst, num, index + 1)
```